# Android ImageView program, how to set imageview according to random function

Tags: android, imageview, logic

Suppose I have 200 images with name of image are:

- image1
- image2
- .
- .
- .
- image200

Now I can generate random number form 1 to 200 using random function. And as all images name is identical except last numerical digit. Can I set my imageview to ( concatenate image and random number).

For example, my random number generate 20, so I will concatenate image+20 which will give me image20 and then I want to set my imageView to image20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following: (Assuming that your images are stored in the drawables folder).

1) MainActivity1.class:---------

```
public class MainActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageView iv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.layout10);

    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);

    // initial
    generatePicture();

    // onClick generate a different one.
    iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            generatePicture();
        }
    });

}

private void generatePicture(){

    Random r = new Random();
    int i1 = r.nextInt(200) + 1;// generates a number between 1 and 200 including both ends.

    try {
        iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(getResources().getIdentifier("image" + i1, "drawable", getPackageName())));
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

2) layout10.xml:-------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/iv"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```